# What underlies the fact $K,H\vartriangleleft G,K\cap H=\mathbf{0},KH=G\implies K\times H\cong G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory

Let $K,H\vartriangleleft G$ be two normal subgroups. I know that if $K\cap H=\mathbf{0}$ and $KH=G$ then $K\times H\cong G$.

I'm trying to understand what is it about the category of groups which makes this statement true. Since intersection and multiplication of *normal* subgroups are respectively their meet and join in the subobject poset of $G$, the conditions are $K\wedge H=\bf 0$ and $K\vee H=G$.

For linear categories, we may use the fact binary unions are effective to calculate the union as the pushout of $K,H$ along $K\wedge H$, which is their coproduct=biproduct=product, and we're done.

But groups have no biproducts. So what's the story from the categorical perspective?

**Added.** Just after asking this question I realized I should check Borceux and Bourne's book on protomodular categories. There lies a section on complemented subobjects in unital categories. Proposition 1.12.4 gives almost everything I need - I think everything except union. Thus, I think my question reduces to asking whether subobjects are complemented if and only if they are normal (kernels of something) and are complemented in the naive sense that their meet and join are respectively zero and everything in the subobject poset.

Comment: Actually, the intersection is never empty. You mean for it to be trivial.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft sorry, fixing.

Comment: It is very unusual to call the trivial group $0$ when not dealing with abelian groups (not wrong of course, just unusual).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I just thought to use this notation since the trivial group is a zero object, i.e both initial and terminal..

Comment: Sure, in the category it makes sense (though it might still be a bit of a poor idea since usually we are mainly interested in $0$-objects when the category is abelian), but on the group level it looks weird.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft would you use $\mathbf{1}$ instead, or $ \left\{ 1 \right\} $?

Comment: @Arrow Formally, $\;\{1\}\;$ , a la mathematicians writing mathematics, just $\;1\;$ is enough. People who knows understand.

Comment: How would you express a semi-direct product in category theory?

Comment: Are there any online notes that I could consult to know a bit more about the use of categories in group-theory?

Comment: @BogaertsMarc see section 5.2 of Borceux and Bourn's book :)

Comment: @arrow can I consult online?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What makes the statement true is that the category of groups is not only pointed with finite limits, but also **protomodular**, i.e.

1. split epimorphisms have pullbacks
2. pullbacks of split epimorphisms reflect isomorphisms

The relevant proposition is then Proposition 3.3.2 in Borceux and Bourn's *Mal'cev, Protomodular, and Homological Categories*. Reworded to match the notation of your question, it states

**Proposition 3.3.2.** Consider a pair of normal subobjects $H\hookrightarrow G\hookleftarrow K$ with $H\cap G=0$ in a pointed protomodular category with finite limits. Then

1. There is a unique morphism $H\times K\xrightarrow{t} G$ so that $H\hookrightarrow G\hookleftarrow K$ factor as the induced inclusions $H\hookrightarrow H\times K\hookleftarrow K$ followed by $H\times K\xrightarrow{t}G$.
2. Furthermore, $H\times K\xrightarrow{t} G$ is a normal subobject, so the union of $H$ and $K$ in the poset of subobjects of $G$.

Protomodularity is the topic of Chapter 3 of the book, it's introduced in Section 3.1., normality is discussed in Section 3.2., and the above proposition is in Section 3.3.

Note that that Theorem 3.1.6. characterizes which algebraic theories have protomodular categories of models

**Theorem 3.1.6.**
The category of models of an algebraic theory is protomodular if and only if it can be axiomatized so that

- there are $n$ constants $e_1,\dots,e_n$
- there are $n$ binary "division'' operations for which the constants are units, i.e. $\phi_i$ with $\phi_i(x,x)=e_i$
- there is a $n+1$-ary "multiplication" operation for which the division operators give a kind of multilinear inverse in that $\theta (\phi_1(x,y),\dots,\phi_n(x,y),y)=y$.

The necessary and sufficient conditions to get a pointed protomodular category of models (to which the proposition applies) is that the constants $e_1,\dots,e_n$ are all the same constant $e$.

In particular, a simple class of algebras whose models are pointed protomdular categories have

- a unique constant constant $e$
- a binary "multiplication" operation and a binary "division" operation so that $x/x=e$ and $x\cdot(y/x)=y$.

So basically, the simple case is that your theory should admit a (one-sided) group operation without the associativity conditions (so an unsymmetric loop). The more complicated case is that an $n+1$-ary operations has $n$ divisions as above.

Comment: Looking at proposition 1.12.4, it seems that if the cooperator of two normal subobjects with zero union were itself a monomorphism then their union as subobjects would be isomorphic to their product. Am I missing something?

Comment: Also, it seems to that the union of subobjects has the same universal property as the image of their coproduct. But this seems very strange as the theorem you site would imply the existence of some biproducts... What's going on here?

Comment: Look at Definition 1.2.5 again: a pointed category with finite limits is **unital** if and only if the union of the subobjects $X\hookrightarrow X\times Y\hookleftarrow Y$ is $X\times Y$ itself. I would call a monomorphic cooperator an "internal direct product" of subobjects; then a category with finite limits is unital if and only if whenenver an internal direct product of two subobjects exists, it is the union of the two subobjects.

Comment: Furthermore, Proposition 1.2.18 shows that if you have a coproduct, then $X\sqcup Y\to X\times Y$ is strongly epimorphic. This implies that if the internal direct product of two subobjects exists, it is the (strong) image of the coproduct of the two subobjects. It also implies that $X\sqcup Y\cong X\times Y$ if and only if $X\rightarrow X\sqcup Y\leftarrow Y$ have a cooperator (I forget if we have enough to conclude coproduct injections are monomorphisms).

Comment: Does $X\sqcup Y\cong X\times Y$ imply $X$ or $Y$ are $\bf 0$ by any chance?

Comment: of course not: $X\sqcup Y\cong X\times Y$ holds in any additive category.

Comment: Sorry, I meant in nonlinear categories.

Comment: I'm a bit late to this, but your characterization of pointed protomodular varieties is wrong. You seem to consider that you need to take the case $n=1$ of the previous theorem to get a unique constant, but the $n$ constants need not be distinct; so actually you can just take the same characterization and just add the condition that all constants are equal.

Comment: you are right of course, thank you!